# Twilio Invalid Access Token Signature (iOS - Swift)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio's latest SDK they released on CocoaPods as of today. I am trying to implement VOIP feature to my app with Twilio Programmable Voice. My backend is .net which also uses the latest release of Twilio Helper Library for C#.

My client code looks like:

```swift
fetchAccessToken { (accessToken: String) in

        TwilioVoice.register(withAccessToken: accessToken, deviceToken: deviceToken) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("An error occurred while registering: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                NSLog("Successfully registered for VoIP push notifications.")
            }
        }

    }
```

What I get in the console is as following:

```
voipTestWithTwilio[2431:517236] [ERROR TwilioVoice] Inside register:deviceToken:completion:, failed to register for Twilio push notifications. Error:Invalid access token signature
voipTestWithTwilio[2431:517236] An error occurred while registering: Invalid access token signature
```

This is the C# code that actually creates the token:

```cs
var grant = new VoiceGrant
            {
                OutgoingApplicationSid = outgoingApplicationSid
            };

            var grants = new HashSet<IGrant> { { grant } };

            var token = new Token(
                accountSid: accountSid,
                signingKeySid: apiKey,
                secret: apiSecret,
                identity: identity,
                grants: grants
            );
            return token.ToJwt();
```

I have been looking for the issue on the internet, nothing helped so far. I have tried contacting them but have not got any response back. I also tried creating new api keys and even a new project for a couple times on Twilio. Can anybody say something about the issue?

**UPDATE**

I added push notification sid to VoiceGrant and now I’m getting **403 Forbidden**.

On [Twilio error codes page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/error-codes) it is explained as: “**The expiration time provided in the Access Token exceeds the maximum duration allowed.**” which is definitely not my case. However, I tried passing expiration parameter in `Token` constructor with various values which didn’t change the result.

The problem is still persisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was because my server returned the token with quotation mark.

I remember print(token)'ing on client (iOS) to see whether there is encoding issue or something and all I see was a proper token between quotation marks. Since token is a string value, I didn't pay attention to quotation part of it. That's where I was wrong.